# How to make a div scroll if the text overflows HTML/CSS? (without fixed height)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML structure:

```html
<body>
    <header class="header"></header>
    <div class="col-sm-4 sidebar" id="sidebar">
 <div class="accordion-1"></div>
 <div class="accordion-2">i want vertical scroll for this div without defining height</div>
 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 container no-padding"></div>
  </body>
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAIxF.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD3Kk.png)

I have a tow accordian inside the sidebar. So I need a scroll bar in the last red backrounded div if the contents overflows.

Comment: `overflow: auto;`???

Comment: <body>
    <header class="header"></header>
    <div class="col-sm-4 sidebar" id="sidebar">
 <div class="accordion-1"></div>
 <div class="accordion-2">i want vertical scroll for this div without defining height</div>
 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 container no-padding"></div>
  </body>

Comment: overflow: auto; works if i fix the height. i want to div strech down based on the veiwport height.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the last red backrounded `div` it's `CSS`:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Or if you want the scroll bar to appear only **if** the content overflows:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: This would add scrollbar even if content doesn't overflowing parent container

Comment: @A.Wolff Correct, isn't that what he wants?

Comment: I guess OP wants `auto`: <<So I need a scroll bar in the last red backrounded div **if** the contents overflows.>>

Comment: Just one thing, OP didn't mention the content could overflow only vertically :) But you get my point anyway... ;) EDIT: i see, in title, he mentions the height, so i guess you are completly right

Comment: @A.Wolff Haha yeah but the image shows a somewhat example of what he wants with the scrollbar only visible vertically so :P

Comment: overflow-y: scroll; is not working without defing div height

Comment: @RizwanI What about `auto`?

Comment: @RizwanI Then please consider to provide in question a minimalistic sample replicating issue, not just an image